# Get AccessToken when Login in from OAuth2 LoginFrom

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I'm using spring OAuth2 loginForm and access_token way to authenticate. But when I login in, I can not get access to resource server which needs access_token authorization.

How can I get access_token when I login in?

Should I create access_token by myself manually?

What I config with spring security is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, proxyTargetClass = true)
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private SpringDataMyBatisUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Override
    @Autowired
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth
        .userDetailsService(this.userDetailsService)
        .passwordEncoder(Manager.PASSWORD_ENCODER);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring()
            .antMatchers(
                      "/druid/**",
                      "/images/**"
            );
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.addFilterBefore(new CorsFilter(), ChannelProcessingFilter.class);
    }

    @Order(1)
    @Configuration
    @EnableAuthorizationServer
    public static class AuthorizationServerConfig extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

        private final AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;
        @Autowired
        private SpringDataMyBatisClientDetailsService clientDetailsService;

        @Autowired
        public AuthorizationServerConfig(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
            this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
        }

        /**
         * Defines the security constraints on the token endpoints /oauth/token_key and /oauth/check_token
         * Client credentials are required to access the endpoints
         *
         * @param oauthServer
         * @throws Exception
         */
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerSecurityConfigurer oauthServer) throws Exception {
            oauthServer
//          .passwordEncoder(Client.PASSWORD_ENCODER)
            .tokenKeyAccess("permitAll()")
            .checkTokenAccess("isAuthenticated()");
        }

        /**
         * Defines the authorization and token endpoints and the token services
         *
         * @param endpoints
         * @throws Exception
         */
        @Override
        public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception {
            endpoints
            .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager)
            .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancer())
            .tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
            clients
            .withClientDetails(clientDetailsService);
        }

        @Bean
        public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer() {
            return new CustomTokenEnhancer();
        }

    }

    @Order(3)
    @Configuration
    @EnableResourceServer
    public static class ApiResources extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private RestAuthenticationEntryPoint restAuthenticationEntryPoint;
        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationSuccessHandler successHandler;
        @Autowired
        private AuthenticationFailureHandler failureHandler;
        @Autowired
        private TokenStore tokenStore;

        @Override
        public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
            resources
            .tokenStore(tokenStore);
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .antMatcher("/api/**")
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(restAuthenticationEntryPoint)
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .successHandler(successHandler)
                .failureHandler(failureHandler)
                .and()
            .logout();
        }

    }

    @Order(4)
    @Configuration
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            http
            .csrf().disable()
            .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
            .formLogin()
                .loginPage("/authention/login")
                .defaultSuccessUrl("/", true)
                .failureUrl("/authention/login?error")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutSuccessUrl("/authention/login?success")
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionFixation().migrateSession();
        }

    }

    @Bean
    public static AuthenticationSuccessHandler myAuthenticationSuccessHandler() {
        return new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationSuccessHandler();
    }

    @Bean
    public static AuthenticationFailureHandler myAuthenticationFailureHandler() {
        return new SavedRequestAwareAuthenticationFailureHandler();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you configure spring-oauth in your app you can access REST APIs to get the tokens, revoke tokens etc.
See this [link](http://www.baeldung.com/rest-api-spring-oauth2-angularjs) For basic oauth configuration for a spring boot application. And also go through the [API reference](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html)

Sample OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfig :

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2AuthorizationServerConfig extends      AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter {

@Override
public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception {
    clients
            .inMemory()
            .withClient("hello")
            .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "refresh_token")
            .authorities("ROLE_APP")
            .scopes("read", "write")
            .secret("secret");
     }
}
```

And the SecurityConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.test.config"})
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {


@Override
public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/resources/**");
}

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
            .csrf()
            .disable();
    http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .anyRequest().access("#oauth2.hasScope('read')")
            .and()
            .exceptionHandling()
            .authenticationEntryPoint(oauthAuthenticationEntryPoint())
            .accessDeniedHandler(oAuth2AccessDeniedHandler());
    http
            .formLogin()
            .loginPage("/login")
            .failureUrl("/")
            .permitAll()
            .and()
            .logout()
            .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
            .permitAll();
}
}
```

After you configure your application. You can access the REST API as below.

1. For getting the token you need to access this URL:

   `localhost:8080/oauth/token?grant_type=password&client_id=hello&client_secret=secret&username=admin&password=password`

This will authenticate the user if it is successful then the token is generated as shown below:

```
{
    "access_token": "0307d70f-e3da-40f4-804b-f3a8aba4d8a8",
    "token_type": "bearer",
    "refresh_token": "daf21f97-f425-4245-8e47-19e4c87000e8",
    "expires_in": 119,
    "scope": "read write"
}
```

2. After getting this token you can access the REST APIs of your application just by passing this token. For example, if you have a URL "/hello" then
   put a request appending the token which you obtained through above step.

   `"http://localhost:8080/hello?access_token=0307d70f-e3da-40f4-804b-f3a8aba4d8a8"`

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answers first. I only want a user who has been already logged can also access the rest api.

Comment: That's what I have mentioned in my answer. First the user will be authenticated and the token will be generated. Now if the user wants to access your REST API he should provide a valid token. You need to append the `?access_token=[generated token here]` to the url. Only if the token is valid, the user can access your REST API.

Comment: `http.authorizeRequests()` in method `protected void configure(HttpSecurity http)` will allow you customize accessing the urls for the users. 
            

This will

Comment: Hi, I have been updated my question, what I had do is to create a resource server. From your answers, what should I do? Remove the resource server's loginForm method?